# FASM - If file exists - Using GetFileAttributes - INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES value?

Tags: winapi, assembly, file-exists, fasm

I am using GetFileAttributesA to determine if a file exists or not, in FASM. I know that if the file does not exists the return value will be INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES, but I am not sure how to check for this value.

My Code:

```
invoke GetFileAttributes,lpFileName
cmp    eax,IDK WHAT TO CHECK FOR
je     notfound
jne    found
invoke ExitProcess,0
```

Seeing as the compiler does not recognize INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES as a value:

```
cmp    eax,INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES
```

Will not work.

Does anyone know the value for this constant, so that I can simply enter it manually?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

---

After the response from Jens Björnhager, the following is the working code for anyone else interested:

```
invoke GetFileAttributes,lpFileName
cmp    eax,-1
je     notfound
jne    found
invoke ExitProcess,0
```

Or Even:

```
invoke GetFileAttributes,lpFileName
cmp    eax,$ffffffff
je     notfound
jne    found
invoke ExitProcess,0
```

Thanks again Jens Björnhager!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES` is defined as **-1 ($ffffffff)**, so check for that.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using magic numbers in code, you should use properly defined macro INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES. This macro defined in kernel32.inc in INCLUDE folder of fasm installation. You can include this inc file like this

include 'c:\path\to\fasm\INCLUDE\EQUATES\KERNEL32.INC'

or you can add only high level include like

include 'c:\path\to\fasm\INCLUDE\win32a.inc' (or win32w.inc if you use unicode version of winapi)

or if you set include value in Environment section of fasmw.ini just :

include 'win32a.inc'

Comment: I do include win32a.inc, in all of my FASM projects actually...

Wouldn't including KERNEL32.INC increase the size of the output file of my application?

EDIT:

To make it clear, INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES is NOT defined when only including win32a.inc.

Thanks for the great response!

Comment: >>  Wouldn't including KERNEL32.INC increase the size of the output file of my application? --- No, of couse, there are only definitions of functions. Sorry, i has mistake, i think about INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, that defined =(. INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES is missing, yes. Best workaround is to define in start of file INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES = -1 and avoid using of magic numbers )

Comment: Yes, I can of course define it myself now that I know the value. Thanks for the help! :)